# fill structure in a custom function of std::min_element() using boost::bind()

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, vector, iterator

Trying to save one iteration over my vector.

I have a `vector<T>` I need to find a minimum element in the vector.

I am using `std::min_element`. Now there is a requirement to create a custom structure, which has elements of `<T>` plus few extra, computed on the fly.

So I am trying to use a function with `boost::bind()` like this:

```
std::vector<MyStruct> myStructObj;
typename std::vector< T >::iterator it = std::min_element(V.begin(), V.end(), boost::bind(BuildStructAndFindMin, myStructObj, _1, _2));
```

but how should I define BuildStructAndFindMin function? Till now, i never needed to create a custom function like this.

1. _1 and _2 represent two ref objects to contents of V. But which one is least of them? I mean: the `std::min_element()'s` definition is going to iterate over a vector. For a fist call, it would simply send first two elements. For a second call, third element from vector and last_found_min element will be sent. Which, _1 or _2 is going to be this last_found_min?
   How to return an iterator? My vague sketch is like this:

   ```
   std::vector< T >::iterator BuildStructAndFindMin (std::vector<MyStruct>& myStructObj, const T &a, const T &b)
   {
       if(<a_min_condition>) // I am aware of this if statement. Just assume it to be a<b
       {
           // the point which is greater - create a struct object for that
           // and push_back in myStructObj

           return //what?;
       }
       else
       {
           // the point which is greater - create a struct object for that
           // and push_back in myStructObj

           return //what?
       }
   }
   ```

and after calling this function, I will have a `min_element`, but it will not be present in myStructObj. So I will insert it at the beginning.

The whole point in doing this drama is to save one iteration.

The easiest way out would have been: iterate over a vector and build a structure. And then call `std::min_element()`. But somehow, I am fighting for few nanoseconds and time is money in this case.

Comment: i think my return type should be bool, but then how should I get reference to least element at the end of everything?

Comment: i can't figure out your actual requirements. can you rephrase the question with a synopsis of what the overall operation should achieve? Perhaps with a working code example that achieves it inefficiently?

Comment: @RichardHodges, I have asked another question. Editing this would have nullified op's answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34559219/fill-structure-while-finding-min-element-c

Comment: Have you looked into boost::accumulators?  This seems like a problem that library solves.  Since you're already including boost in your code, you might as well try to see if you can benefit from that library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3rd argument of `std::min_element` can be a class like this:

```
struct myclass { 
    bool operator() (int i,int j) { return i<j; }
};
```

In a comperator class you can store any information you want and you can implement any logic you want. if it is necessary you can even pass somthing like `boost::bind` as an argument to its constructor.

```
template< typename T, typename TSTRUCT, typename TBIND >
struct MyCompare
{
    MyCompare( TSTRUCT &myStruct, T &ref1, T &ref2, TBIND bind )
        : _myStruct( myStruct )
        , _1( ref1 )
        , _2( ref2 )
        , _bind( bind )
    {}
    bool operator()( const T &a, const T &b )
    {
        // enter your code her
        return ...;
    }

    TSTRUCT &_myStruct;
    T &_1;
    T &_2;
    TBIND &_bind; 
};

template< typename T > 
struct MyStruct
{
    std::vector< T > V;
    T obj1;
    T obj2;
  typename std::vector< T >::iterator it = std::min_element(V.begin(), V.end(), MyCompare<T,MyStruct>( *this, obj1, obj2, boost::bind( ... what ever ... ) ) );
};
```

Comment: I accepted your answer because that definitely works. However I do not want to introduce new class for this task. May be my question was to abstract. I have asked another one - more clearer one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34559219/fill-structure-while-finding-min-element-c

Answer (score 0):

One solution, which I find to be simple and elegant, is to overload the `<` operator. Let's say your `MyStruct` structure is defined as follows.

```
struct MyStruct
{
    std::string str;
    int num;

    MyStruct(int initial_value)
        : num(initial_value)
    {
    }

    bool operator<(const MyStruct& other)
    {
        return num < other.num;
    }
};
```

So you have a few members, there's a constructor, this is all standard stuff. However, note the `operator<` function, all it does is return `true` if `this` MyStruct is considered to be "less than" the `other` MyStruct, and `false` otherwise. Now you can use `MyStruct` in `std::min_element` just like you would with integers. Take a look:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<MyStruct> objects = {10, 20, 15, 2, 25, 5, 30};
    std::vector<MyStruct>::iterator minval = std::min_element(objects.begin(), objects.end());

    std::cout << "Minimum value is " << minval->num << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This code prints out 2 for the minimum value. Now, you may have noticed the use of the C++11 initialization list. This syntax works in this case because the values being passed in the initialization list can be fed into a constructor of `MyStruct`. I'll let you initialize your vector of `MyStruct`s however you like but I had to come up with a full definition for the example, but the point here is that by overloading the `<` operator, you can use `MyStruct`s in `std::min_element` very easily.

Edit:

I forgot to mention, this solution only works, of course, if you can afford to change the public interface of your class to support the `<` operator overload. I guess you may have reasons to not be able to do that.