# fill structure while finding min_element, C++

Tags: c++, boost, vector, iterator, std

I want to fill some structure while finding minimum element. Pl find the code below

```
tyoedef struct Point
{
    double x, y;
}Point;
```

I have a `vector of points` - `std::vector<Point> V` in which i have few thousand points.

There is another struct I have

```
typedef struct cart
{
    Point pt;
    double val_1; // computed using only Pt
    double val_2; // computer using only Pt
}cart;
```

Now I have two tasks:

1. I need to find minimum element from structure V.
2. Fill the structure cart, which is directly dependent on V.

   I can do this using following code.

   ```
   std::vector<cart> vCart;
   for(unsigned i = 0; i < V.size(); ++i)
   {
       cart thsElement;
       thsElement.pt = V[i];
       thsElement.val_1 = compute_val_1(V[i]);
       thsElement.val_2 = compute_val_2(V[i]);
       vCart.push_back(thsElement)
   }

   auto it = std::min_element(vCart.begin(), vCart.end(), lex_sort);

   bool lex_sort(cart const &a, cart const &b)
   {
       if(a.pt.x < b.pt.x) return true;
       if(a.pt.x == b.pt.x) return (a.pt.y < b.pt.y);
   }
   ```

Now there is an evident problem with this implementation.

There are two loops. One for filling the structure and other for finding the min element (`std::min_element()` has to have a loop to iterate over all the values). I am fighting for few miliseconds' improvement. So this is not a good code. Moreover, this seems so `C_style`

So I came up with following code.

```
    std::vector<cart> vCart;
    std::iterator <vCart> st_ite;

    auto it = std::min_element(V.begin(), V.end(), boost::bind(FillStruct_LexSort, st_ite, _1, _2)); // V is a vector of Point

    bool FillStruct_LexSort(std::insert_iterator< std::vector<Cart>> vcpInput, const Point &a, const Point &b)
    {
        Cart thsPt;
        if(a.x() < b.x())
        {
            thsPt.pt = b;
            thsPt.val_1 = compute_val_1(b);
            thsPt.val_2 = compute_val_2(b);
            (*vcpInput++) = (thsPt);
            return true;
        }
        if (a.x() == b.x())
        {
            if(a.y() < b.y())
            {
                thsPt.pt = b;
                thsPt.val_1 = compute_val_1(b);
                thsPt.val_2 = compute_val_2(b);

                (*vcpInput++) = (thsPt);
                return true;
            }
        }

        thsPt.pt = a;
        thsPt.val_1 = compute_val_1(b);
        thsPt.val_2 = compute_val_2(b);

        (*vcpInput++) = (thsPt);
        return false;
    }
```

Now, the problem is - I get segmentation fault. I do not know how should I use iterator to insert a value. I tried passing reference to vCart, but vCart is empty after calling min_element(..). I even tried insert_iterator, but with no success.

So pl suggest.

Comment: You could simply keep track of the smallest element as you fill the vector?

Comment: You will have better improvement with `std::vector::reserve` than to *move* the 2 jobs from two loops into one.

Comment: The 2 loops are not a problem btw...

Comment: Please elaborate, how iterating same vector twice is not a problem? Does not it take more time than iterating once and doing two tasks?

Comment: You are using st_ite uninitialized. You may want to initialize it to `std::back_inserter(vCart)`.

Comment: You don't change complexity (`O(n)` in both case). With cache, branch prediction and optimisation, not sure that you even win the time of the avoided comparison by step in the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want something like:

```
bool lex_sort(const Point& lhs, const Point& rhs)
{
    return std::tie(lhs.x, lhs.y) < std::tie(rhs.x, rhs.y);
}
```

and then

```
auto it = std::min_element(V.begin(), V.end(), &lex_sort);
if (it == V.end()) {
    // V is empty.
} else {
    Cart thsPt;
    thsPt.pt = it;
    thsPt.val_1 = compute_val_1(*it);
    thsPt.val_2 = compute_val_2(*it);
    return thsPt;
}
```

Note that if `val_1`/`val_2` always depend of `pt`, you can add a constructor for `Cart` which take a `Point`

Comment: yeah.. and did you forget `vCart.push_back(thsPt)` before return `thsPt`? just for the sake of completeness.

Comment: I may miss something, but If you just want the minimum, you don't have to return a `vector` (with only 1 element)... Note that in your snippet of code, it is not clear what you do with your `auto it = `...

Comment: of course, further I have a lot of work to do with vCart. That did not fit into question's context and therefor I did not mention it. min_element is just a small piece, otherwise why would I create a new struct with point and val_1 and val_2. As title of the question suggests, I want min_element as well as a structure filled..